# RXJS 6: new version of HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I am in the process of adding `rxjs_compat` to my project in order to move to v6 of libraries.

However the existing `HttpInterceptor` for global error handling no longer compiles. Not sure where to go with it. Tried all sorts. Getting type mismatches with everything tried.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, of, empty } from "rxjs";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(err => of(HttpErrorResponse)),
      map(err => {
        let message: string;
         this.toastr.error(`${message}`, "Application Error");
        return Observable.empty<HttpEvent<any>>();
      })
    );
  }
}
```

> src/app/shared/http-error-interceptor.ts(26,27): error TS2339:
>   Property 'empty' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

`empty` is now a constant, but doesn't accept a type, so that does not work either. Also could not find much in [the upgrade notes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#dep-methods)

**EDIT**

although interestingly this compiles:

```
return Observable.of<HttpEvent<any>>();
```

Comment: Does trying `return empty();` work? `empty` is now a constant (`EMPTY`), and function (`empty(scheduler?: SchedulerLike)`).

Comment: Congrats for your gentleman-inspired avatar's name. Long live Jenson Button \o/

Comment: and the Monkey King!!

Comment: @statosdotcom tried that but `intercept` it type safe `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`

Comment: How about this: `return of<HttpEvent<any>>();`

Comment: maybe a dumb question, but why dont you throw error observable instead of returning typed empty one?

Comment: interesting. the rxjs-lint command just finished. this is what it did! `return observableOf<HttpEvent<any>>();` which  is an alias for `of`. presumably that is implicitly empty?

Comment: @deezg open to best suggestions thanks

Comment: but i dont want to throw, just continue as the error has been handled with a toast. all the user needs to know. the actual code is a bit more verbose

Comment: How did you make this work? `return of<HttpEvent<any>>();` does not compile for me: Type 'Observable<Observable<HttpEvent<any>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'. The accepted answer also does not work because of type safety.

Comment: I also tried `throwError()`: Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. `import {EMPTY} from 'rxjs';`
2. Replace return `Observable.empty()` with

   `return EMPTY;`

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't figure out how to return something that the compiler accepts, but was at least able to throw an error. The code compiles and works, but as a beginner in Rxjs not sure if it is correct.

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const xhr = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
    });
    return next.handle(xhr).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          } else {
            this.snack.open('Communication error: ' + err.status + ' - ' + err.statusText, null,
             {duration: 5000, panelClass: 'snack-error', verticalPosition: 'top'});
          }
          return throwError('backend comm error');
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: presenting a detailed exception message to your end user is rarely a good choice

Comment: @Arthur if err is not an instanceof `HttpErrorResponse` you don't return anything inside of your `catchError`

Comment: @CoreyCole true, at least logging the other error somewhere would be a good idea.

Comment: I think you have to return something so that the observable chain can continue. It says [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) to always return an observable from the `catchError` function