# Angular Wait until variable has been initialized

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm about to create a service for a web application. The first step is to get a token via the rest API. As soon as this token is available, it should be sent as a header to get more information.

My problem is that it executes the function to get more information before the variable is set. ( The header is empty, but if I set the token manually it works).

How can I make my function wait until the variable has its value?

Thanks

```
gettoken(): void {
this.http.get<InitResponse>('URL' + '/token').subscribe(data => {
    this.token = data.token;
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
    getmoreInfo();
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
      console.log('Client-side error occured.');
    } else {
      console.log('Server-side error occured.');
    }
  }
);
```

}

Comment: How you are setting token in header?

Comment: You have to make `gettoken` asynchronous. Simply wrap it into `Observable` and return token instead of returning `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Add async and await to your function to make it load asynchronous.

https://javascript.info/async-await

heres examples for practice

https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77

angular ^

when you put async on the function

and then await for the steps it runs the steps after each other, which is what asynchronous code means

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please change my code to work? I put Async in front of the function, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Look at his function. There is no point to use `async/await`. Right now it does not return any value. He use `RxJs` so he can just return `observable` instead of wrapping everything in additional `Promise`.

Comment: It's sound true what @KarolTrybulec says, but it was also just an suggestion i have tried before to make it work, and it did. So i just shared of my experience.

Comment: maybe try :

`this.http.get<InitResponse>('URL' + '/token').subscribe( (async) data => {
    await this.token = data.token;
    await localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
    await getmoreInfo();
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
      console.log('Client-side error occured.');
    } else {
      console.log('Server-side error occured.');
    }
  }
);`

Answer (score 0):

This is my getToken method :

```
  getToken(idProfile: string): Observable<boolean> {
    let urlAPIToken: string = urlAPIAuth;

    urlAPIToken += '/token?id_profile=' + idProfile;
    let res = encodeURIComponent(urlAPIToken);   

    return this.http.get(urlAPIToken, { withCredentials: true }).pipe(
      map(result => {    
        let token = result.toString();
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        return true;
      }));
  }
```

And, for sending it to any request, I use an interceptor that send the token in all HTTP request:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_NAME);

      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
```

Example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475213/rxjs-6-new-version-of-httpinterceptor)